# Gusto organolettico?

Tags: meaning

Stavo leggendo un post sulla frutta esotica, e trovo spesso il termine organolettico, ma non riesco a capirne il senso, perché lo rapporta col gusto, come si descrive il gusto organolettico?

http://www.mattiaberera.it/perche-lacerola-fa-bene-proprieta-benefici-valori-nutrizionali/

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!

Comment: Un appunto: nel link che hai indicato non trovo nella pagina l'estratto che contiene l'espressione gusto organolettico. Potresti per favore includere il passaggio in cui l'hai trovato in modo da contestualizzare meglio?

Comment: Benvenuto! L'uso qui è, prima di porre una domanda, di fare un minimo di ricerca per conto proprio. Hai cercato questa parola su qualche dizionario?

Answer (score 4):

Secondo Treccani per [organolettico](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/organolettico/) si intende:

> **organolèttico** agg. [dal fr. *organoleptique*, comp. del gr. *ὄργανον* «organo» (di senso) e *ληπτός* «che si può prendere, afferrare»] (pl. m. *-ci*). – In fisiologia e in merceologia, detto
>   delle proprietà di una sostanza che possono essere percepite dai
>   sensi, come odore, sapore o colore: *caratteri o. di un prodotto, di
>   una merce, di un vino, di un formaggio, ecc.*; analogam., *esame,
>   saggio o.*, fatto per valutare e controllare tali caratteri e
>   proprietà.

Wikipedia riporta la spiegazione dell'espressione [proprietà organolettiche](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propriet%C3%A0_organolettiche) e una loro possibile classificazione:

> Le proprietà organolettiche di un alimento sono l'insieme delle sue
>   caratteristiche fisiche e chimiche percepite dagli organi di senso
>   (olfatto, vista, gusto) e che nel complesso suscitano nella persona
>   delle reazioni emotive più o meno intense.
>
> Una rigorosa classificazione delle singole proprietà organolettiche
>   non può prescindere dalla difficoltà di catalogarle schematicamente,
>   in quanto alcune, per la loro complessità, sono in realtà composte da
>   un insieme di caratteristiche percepite globalmente. Ad esempio,
>   l'aspetto dell'alimento è determinato da un insieme di caratteristiche
>   percepite principalmente con la vista, ma secondariamente anche con il
>   tatto e l'udito. La letteratura riporta perciò differenti schemi di
>   classificazione in base al grado di genericità di una determinata
>   proprietà. Fra le proprietà normalmente menzionate rientrano le
>   seguenti:
>
> - colore, percepito con la vista
> - dimensione, percepita principalmente con la vista
> - forma, percepita principalmente con la vista
> - condizione, percepita principalmente con la vista
> - sapore, percepito con il gusto e l'olfatto
> - odore, percepito con l'olfatto.
> - consistenza e tessitura, percepite con la vista, il tatto e l'udito
>
> Nel complesso queste caratteristiche si possono riassumere in tre
>   proprietà generali che sono valutate, più o meno consciamente, nel
>   seguente ordine cronologico:
>
> 1. Aspetto fisico: in questa proprietà si riassumono la forma, la
>      dimensione, il colore e, ad un primo esame, la tessitura e la
>      condizione. Nella percezione dell'aspetto assume un ruolo primario
>      la vista.
> 2. Caratteristiche chimiche: in questa proprietà si riassumono l'odore
>      e il sapore. La percezione delle caratteristiche chimiche è una
>      prerogativa dei chemiorecettori dislocati nella lingua e nel naso.
> 3. Caratteristiche meccaniche: in questa proprietà si riassumono la
>      resistenza meccanica, la tessitura, l'omogeneità, la croccantezza,
>      ecc. Si tratta di caratteristiche che vengono percepite in modo
>      complesso dal tatto e, in qualche caso, con l'intervento dell'udito.

Il gusto è un senso che ci consente di percepire il sapore, che è una proprietà organolettica di un cibo, ma dire gusto organolettico mi pare privo di senso.